# How to store an array of an inventory in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

The end user has an inventory such as:
dogs:0, cats:3, dragons:20 etc you get the point.

So for a 30 inventory string array, what is the best way to store the values in mysql
and then use them with php? do i need to use json for this? because i would like
to update for instance a user "buying" another dragon and update the record occasionally.

Comment: If i may add we are talking about a 200k+ user base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a seperate table for this, which has a reference to the object (if an object table exist), the player it belongs to and the number of items. No need to store a json string in a table.

```
Table Objects
-----------------
id | Object name

Table Inventory
----------------------------------
id | player_id | object_id | count
```

Answer (score 0):

Store in a table containing Id, Name, Quantity. 
You need JSON to communicate with php without reloading the page (AJAX), but it can be generated dynamically.